# How to lower Data Transfer costs on an AWS course platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, cdn

I am calculating the operation costs for a platform we want to develop for a client in AWS. The platform is an online course solution where users can subscribe and access different multimedia contents.

My initial thought was to store the videos in an S3 bucket and simply "feed" them to my back end solution so that the front end can access and show them.

My problem is that when doing the cost estimate I am getting huge cost estimates in Outbound Data Transfer. I don't really know how much traffic the client is expecting so I estimated traffic the following way (this platform is gonna be supported by the state so it will have some traffic):
20MB for every minute of video:

- 2 hours per week for every user
- 200 users per month
- 20MB/m * 60 m/h * 2h/week * 4weeks * 200 = **1.92 TB**
- This, at 0.09 USD / GB gives me **184.23** USD per month...

I don't know if I am not designing a well made solution, if my estimate is wrong... but I find this to be very expensive. Adding other costs this means I have to pay nearly 2 USDs per user. If someone finds a way to reduce costs please let me know!

Thank you

Comment: It's less than $1/user.  What do they pay for the course?

Comment: Your math is a bit off, though in the right ballpark.  1875gb per month is $168.66.  That said, if you can't afford $0.84 per student per month, then yes, the bandwidth charge in AWS will be too expensive for your use case.

Comment: @AnonCoward I guess the solution is either different pricing or limiting video consumption (720p maybe?). Thanks for checking it out!

Comment: Sure, if you're willing to cut the video quality, you can save 40-50% of the bandwidth cost by going from 1080p to 720p.  Also, I'd be curious how you came up with 20MB/m, since I'd expect a bitrate of closer to 4 or 5MB/m for training videos (just checked against a couple of 1080p youtube videos).  20MB/m feels closer to a bitrate for a much more active video.  In the end, if this is still too much cost, you'll need to move some or all of the solution outside of AWS where the bandwidth costs are lower.

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways to lower data transfer costs on an AWS course platform. Here are some suggestions:**

**Use a content delivery network (CDN):** A CDN can help reduce data transfer costs by caching frequently accessed content closer to the user, which reduces the amount of data that needs to be transferred over the network. AWS offers Amazon CloudFront, which is a global CDN that can be used to deliver content with low latency and high transfer speeds.

**Compress content:** Compressing content before sending it over the network can reduce data transfer costs by reducing the amount of data that needs to be transferred. AWS offers services like Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudFront that support compression for certain file types.

Optimize images: Images can be a major source of data transfer costs. Optimizing images by reducing their size, compressing them, or using a lower resolution can significantly reduce data transfer costs. AWS offers services like Amazon S3 and Amazon CloudFront that support image optimization.

**Use AWS Direct Connect:** AWS Direct Connect is a service that allows you to establish a dedicated network connection between your on-premises infrastructure and AWS. This can help reduce data transfer costs by providing a dedicated, private connection with lower latency and higher throughput.

Use AWS Transfer Family: AWS Transfer Family is a fully managed service that allows you to transfer files over the internet using SFTP, FTPS, and FTP protocols. AWS Transfer Family provides options to optimize data transfer and lower costs, such as Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration.

**Monitor data transfer usage:** Monitoring data transfer usage can help you identify areas where you can reduce data transfer costs. AWS offers services like Amazon CloudWatch that can be used to monitor data transfer usage and costs in real-time.

By implementing these suggestions, you can potentially reduce data transfer costs on your AWS course platform.

Comment: is this from your own experience, or is this a Cut & Paste answer from ChatGPT? Your answer doesn't seem to address the specific issues raised in the question.